# Data sent from iOS to NFC tags

Tags: ios, nfc, apdu, ndef, contactless-smartcard

Hi does anyone know how I can get a sample of all raw data sent from iOS to a Mifare tag? At low level (ISO/CEI 14443 part 3 or 4, including REQA/REQB). Even if Apple forbids writing to the tag it seems to send unalterable APDUs anyway under the hood, I'd like to see what it contains too.

I'm looking for any data that may change from session to session, or from an iOS device to another iOS device. And if I can retrieve this data from iOS memory, or guess it.

I am also wondering if the retryinterval parameter corresponds to any parameter sent to the chip at ISO/CEI 14443 part 3 or 4 level, or is it an iOS specific higher level parameter? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfctagcommandconfiguration/2873688-retryinterval

Comment: that's interesting - about the apdu commands being sent. Can't you just emulate a card and log in the conversation? You could also get a sniffer like the Proxmark3

Comment: Hello Saik, thank you for your reply. I'll check this Proxmark3 device, sound interesting. I don't know how to emulate a card, is there any how-to that you recommend? Thanks again!

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can only read NFC on iOS - what you need to operate an NFC "Card" on a mobile device is a Secure Element or Host-Based Card Emulation. Apple does not support HCE, and I don't believe there is a legal/legit way to access the Secure Element. One thing I've heard of is basically via Apple Pay, whereby you set up a card that basically poses as a bank card. I've only heard about this and know nothing of the implementation

Comment: OK, thank you very much for this additional information Saik!